# HTML5 Game Development

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making an illustrated storybook, with the user clicking to read the next part of the story. I've made three different scenes (three different pages). I can switch from scene One to scene two using eventListener, but I am not able to switch from scene Two to scene Three.

I want to be able to switch between the scenes as in

When the user clicks the mouse:

- if the current scene is the first one, go to the second
- if the current scene is the second one, go to the third
- if the current scene is the third one, go back to the first

But I'm not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I should also mention I'm learning the basics so that I can move forward with Game Development. And so this is a very basic code.

Here is my code:

```
var c = document.querySelector("#c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x = document.getElementById("c");
    //Scene One
    function sceneOne(){
       ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(235,247,255)";
       ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 85, 255)";
        ctx.font = "70px Impact";
        ctx.fillText("The Story of Winston", 40, 130); 
    };

   //Scene Two
   function sceneTwo() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,239,255)";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
        ctx.fillStyle="rgb(7, 14, 145)";
        ctx.fillText("Lil Winston is born!", 10, 100);
    };

    //Scee Three
    function sceneThree() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,239,255)";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(7, 14, 145)";
        ctx.fillText("Winston grows up!", 10, 100);
    };
       //Calling scene one
    sceneOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below contains the functionality that you require.

In summary:

- We use the `currentScene` variable to keep track of which screen the user is currently on
- Within our event listener we use a `switch` statement to call the appropriate function to display the next screen, depending on which screen the user is currently on

```js
var c = document.querySelector("#c");
c.width  = 800;
c.height = 200;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Init variable to store screen the user is on
var currentScene;

// Load next screen when user clicks the canvas
c.addEventListener("click", function(){
    switch(currentScene) {
        case 1:
            sceneTwo();
            break;
        case 2:
            sceneThree();
            break;
        case 3:
            sceneOne();
            break;
    }
});

//Scene One
function sceneOne(){
    currentScene = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(235,247,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 85, 255)";
    ctx.font = "70px Impact";
    ctx.fillText("The Story of Winston", 40, 130); 
};

//Scene Two
function sceneTwo() {
    currentScene = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,239,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(7, 14, 145)";
    ctx.fillText("Lil Winston is born!", 10, 100);
};

//Scee Three
function sceneThree() {
    currentScene = 3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,239,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(7, 14, 145)";
    ctx.fillText("Winston grows up!", 10, 100);
};

//Calling scene one
sceneOne();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```